# positioning of serval images inside a div in circle view?how?

Tags: image, css, position

I want to position several images inside a div block. But div CSS properties not applied to image.I want image in round shape.

Comment: Post the code you have so far, if you want a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

For round shape images, you have to use two images.

One is the original image,
and in the second image you should have the only shape area transparent.

Then put the second image on the top of your original one. You will see the result you want.

Comment: users upload only passport size images when user upload it it appears into cirlce shape.@abbas

Comment: Sorry i did not understand your question. User upload the image which you want to show in circle shape? Or user already upload the image in the circle shape?

Comment: User upload a image i want to show in circle shape.

Comment: So take a one passport size image and set the onc circle transparent in it. When customer upload the image show it behind the image with the circle using javascript.